# Reach the page rss from exclude in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to exclude `rss` from the regex for `page.php` so I can reach `rss` correctly via `erik-edgren.nu/rss`. But the code below doesn't understand what I want it to do. Have I missed something?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/rss

RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)$    page.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^rss$    rss-feed.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the order of your rules to make it work correctly:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^rss/?$ rss-feed.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)$ page.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks :D I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.